# Only handle a part of the testcase when the condition is satisfied in pytest

Tags: python, exception, conditional-statements, pytest

I have below pytest case where I need a condition or exception where, if the category is blue, all 4(P1 - P4) should be created.

If its grey, then only P1 and P2 should be created.

But, the testcase should pass in both the categories and I would need to implement both in the same testcase.

Im new to this, so I would be needing help. More details are provided in the code snippet below.

```
....
....
category = eval(data_cim['generic']['category'])
```

**The category is either blue or grey. Blue category has all P1 - P4 and grey has only P1 and P2**

```
def test_01(self):
        resp = self.x.create_p(self.category.p1)
        resp_status = self.x.checkResponseStatus(resp)
        msg = self.x.extraceMessage(resp.text)
        info = msg['error']
        self.assertEqual(resp_status, RESTResponse.PASSED, 'Creating P1 failed')
        self.assertEqual('OK',info, 'Creating P1 failed')

        resp = self.x.create_p(self.category.p2)
        resp_status = self.x.checkResponseStatus(resp)
        msg = self.x.extraceMessage(resp.text)
        info = msg['error']
        self.assertEqual(resp_status, RESTResponse.PASSED, 'Creating P2 failed')
        self.assertEqual('OK',info, 'Creating P2 failed')
```

**If category = blue, continue with the next 2 creations if category is grey,
stop executing the testcase as grey has only p1 and p2**

```
        resp = self.x.create_p(self.category.p3)
        resp_status = self.x.checkResponseStatus(resp)
        msg = self.x.extraceMessage(resp.text)
        info = msg['error']
        self.assertEqual(resp_status, RESTResponse.PASSED, 'Creating P3 failed')
        self.assertEqual('OK',info, 'Creating P3 failed')

        resp = self.x.create_p(self.category.p4)
        resp_status = self.x.checkResponseStatus(resp)
        msg = self.x.extraceMessage(resp.text)
        info = msg['error']
        self.assertEqual(resp_status, RESTResponse.PASSED, 'Creating P4 failed')
        self.assertEqual('OK',info, 'Creating P4 failed')
```

Comment: first off, you need to break the logic in to separate tests, as it stands you have everything defined inside one test case

Comment: Why are you using unittest style assertions? In pytest you can just use plain `assert`